# party finished / was finished

Tags: verbs

> 1. I had a party last night, but the party **finished** too early for me to drink enough to call it a night.
> 2. I had a party last night, but the party **was finished** too early for me to drink enough to call it a night.

I think both of them can be used here and they are the same meaning, but I just wanted to double check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, both *forms* are perfectly acceptable.

**However** -

In American English, at least, we don't generally say that a party "finished".

We are much more likely to use "ended" or "was over".

> I had a party last night but the party **ended** too early for me to drink enough to call it a night.
>
> I had a party last night but the party **was over** too early for me to drink enough to call it a night.

We would *not* use "was ended" or "overed" (which isn't actually a word).

Also, it's a bit redundant to restate "the party", so I recommend using "it" instead.

> I had a party last night but **it** ended too early for me to drink enough to call it a night.
>
> I had a party last night but **it** was over too early for me to drink enough to call it a night.